# String distances and variable substitution costs

Tags: stringdist, variable-substitution

I want to quantify distance between word pairs based on phonological features. Insertion and deletion costs will stay constant but substitution costs will vary according to letter pair which are stored in a matrix. I am thinking of using the stringdist package to do this but I do not know how to incorporate variable substitution costs.

Thanks!